# Bucketing in python and calculating mean for a bucket

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Input Data Sample:
101.csv ( i have similar files for different ID i.e. 102.csv , 209.csv etc)

```
ID  A       B
101 1561.5  4.117647059
101 1757    4.705882353
101 1812    7.692307692
101 2020.5  8.333333333
101 1569    5.833333333
101 1958.5  7
101 1657.5  6
101 823.5   7.142857143
101 1938.5  3.529411765
101 2123    4.705882353
101 747.5   4.761904762
101 1895    8.333333333
101 1806.5  6.111111111
101 1702    8.461538462
101 1332    7.142857143
101 1740.5  4.117647059
101 1832    6.25
101 1966.5  6.111111111
```

I made a bucket and calculated mean with the following code, what i want to do now is to add a column with ID, each bucket should be in different column in header, i have multiple csv files, each file contains different ID. I want my output file to contain result for every id i.e. all the csv files in folder.

```
bins = [650,1000,1350,1700,2050,2400,2750,3000]
a_bins = df.B.groupby(pd.cut(df['A'],bins))
a_bins = a_bins.agg([np.mean])
```

result i am currently getting for each id

```
A   B
650-1000    7.647691597
1000-1350   7.55428538
1350-1700   8.420818076
1700-2050   7.105554845
2050-2400   5.29774235
2400-2750   6.442554031
2750-3100   5.397752428
```

What i need is

```
ID  650-1000    1000-1350   1350-1700   1700-2050   2050-2400   2400-2750   2750-3100
101 7.6476916   7.5542854   8.4208181   7.1055548   5.2977424   6.4425540   5.3977524 
102 7.6576916   6.4425540   8.4508181   7.1155548   7.5542854   6.4725540   5.4077524 
209 7.6876916   8.4208181   7.5542854   5.3977524   7.5542854   5.2977424   7.5542854
```

Comment: I can't see IDs 102, 209 in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
files = Path(".").glob("1*.csv")
my_df_list = []
bins = [650,1000,1350,1700,2050,2400,2750,3000]
columns = ("650-1000","1000-1350","1350-1700","1700-2050","2050-2400","2400-2750","2750-3000")
for file in files:
    file_name = file.name
    file_id = file_name.replace("*.csv","")
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    print(df.columns)
    bins = [650,1000,1350,1700,2050,2400,2750,3000]
    a_bins = df.B.groupby(pd.cut(df['A'],bins))
    a_bins = a_bins.agg([np.mean]).reset_index(drop=True)
    a_bins_df = a_bins.T.copy()
    a_bins_df.columns = columns
    a_bins_df.index = [file_id]
    my_df_list.append(a_bins_df)
df_total = pd.concat(my_df_list,axis=0)
```

Assuming all of the .csv files are in the same directory, following will be the output, I have copied 1.csv as 2.csv to test the above script

```
    650-1000    1000-1350   1350-1700   1700-2050   2050-2400   2400-2750   2750-3000
102 5.952381    7.142857    5.316993    6.422334    4.705882    NaN NaN
101 5.952381    7.142857    5.316993    6.422334    4.705882    NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
bins = [650,1000,1350,1700,2050,2400,2750,3000]
a_bins = df.groupby([pd.cut(df['A'],bins), 'ID']).B
a_bins.agg('mean').reset_index().pivot(index='ID', columns='A', values='B')
```

Like this you'll get:

```
A    (650, 1000]  (1000, 1350]  ...  (2400, 2750]  (2750, 3000]
ID                              ...                            
101     5.952381      7.142857  ...           NaN           NaN
```