# Calculating mean and count of rows for a bucket

Tags: pandas

I have a df as follows

```
MPG    Maker       Price

8     Toyota      20000
12    Toyota      18000
15    Toyota      19000
5     Honda       19000
4     Honda        20000
```

I am looking to bin by MPG and then calculate average price and number of elements in the bin.
The DF I am looking to create is

```
MPG    Maker    Avg_Price   Num_Sold
0-8    Toyota    19000       3
9-15   Honda     19500       2
```

I followed the directions in [Bucketing in python and calculating mean for a bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59562665/bucketing-in-python-and-calculating-mean-for-a-bucket) and was able to get the average price, but I am unable to get the `Num_Sold` to work.
I used

```
bins = [1,8,15]
df_bins = df.MAKER.groupby(pd.cut(df['MPG'],bins))
df_bins = df_bins.agg([np.mean, len]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I thinking about output, do you need averages per `MPG` and `Maker` ? Or only by `MPG` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named aggregation also with column `Maker`:

```
bins = [1,8,15]
df_bins = (df.groupby(['Maker',pd.cut(df['MPG'],bins)])
             .agg(Avg_Price=('Price','mean'),
                  Num_Sold= ('Price', 'size')).reset_index())
```

Or without `Maker` column:

```
bins = [1,8,15]
df_bins = (df.groupby([pd.cut(df['MPG'],bins)])
             .agg(Avg_Price=('Price','mean'),
                  Num_Sold= ('Price', 'size')).reset_index())
print (df_bins)
```